# How to structure a delegate that points to an extension method

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I have a LINQ query, and I want to have a delegate that I can assign the "OrderBy" or "OrderByDescending"  methods to.  The signature of the "[OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)" extension method is:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

Can anyone show me what the delegate would look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning the extension methods to the delegate"? Do you mean the lambda expression to specify the key selector (second argument of OrderBy)?

Comment: I guess the question is about dynamically deciding which extension method to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public delegate IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByFunc<TSource, TKey>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);
```

Usage:

```
public OrderByFunc<TSource, TKey> GetOrderByFunc<TSource, TKey>(bool descending)
{
    if (descending)
    {
        return Enumerable.OrderByDescending;
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.OrderBy;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you'd use this as:  `db.Contacts.GetOrderByFunc(false)(c=>c.LastName);`   ?

Comment: @James Curran: Yes, that's one possible usage. But `GetOrderByFunc` is just an example. I don't know what the OP intends to do with the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can either ignore the "this" parameter when structuring your delegate, or you can construct the delegate from an instance that the delegate hung off of.

```
delegate IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderDelegate<TSource,TKey>
         (IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
          Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function which takes as a parameter an object of the type of the table, and return the value from the object that you want to sort by:

Say you have a Table of `People`, each item is a `Person`, and you want to sort by `LastName`:

```
public static string ByLastName(Person p)
{
     return p.LastName;
}


 db.People.Where(p=>p.age > 25).OrderBy(ByLastName);
```